# Is there any regular expression for English parts of speech identification?

Tags: regex

I need regular expression for English parts of speech.I mean I need regular expression to identify verb,noun,pronoun,adjective,adverb.Please let me know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: English is a natural language that's not a regular language. So no.

Comment: If such a regex exists, I don't think I'd like to cast my eyes upon its horrors...

Comment: You'd need a natural language processing library for the programming language you are using. So the answer is: No.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work with pure regex.

You would have to check against a list (database) of known verbs, nouns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Natural languages are not regular languages. They are not even context-free grammars (like C++ or java are)

Answer (score 0):

NLTK provides an example of this in their documentation.

```
patterns = [
    (r'.*ing$', 'VBG'),               # gerunds
    (r'.*ed$', 'VBD'),                # simple past
    (r'.*es$', 'VBZ'),                # 3rd singular present
    (r'.*ould$', 'MD'),               # modals
    (r'.*\'s$', 'NN$'),               # possessive nouns
    (r'.*s$', 'NNS'),                 # plural nouns
    (r'^-?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?$', 'CD'),  # cardinal numbers
    (r'.*', 'NN')                     # nouns (default)
]
```

Take a look at the section for the The Regular Expression Tagger.
https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html

**Note:** It is important to keep in mind that this is not a viable way to do most part-of-speech tagging tasks, however this method can be effective when used as a `backoff` for a more effective tagger.